# Why isn't element positioned at bottom of container?

Tags: html, css, position

I have a bar chart that includes 5 different sub-containers inside, each a different color. I want the 'chicken' sub-container to be on the bottom of the bar (zero bottom-margin), but for some reason it's not working. In fact, when I use absolute positioning for the sub-container, it doesn't even show up. (note: the height of each sub-container is determined by Javascript and I've tested the JS and it works fine so I think the issue is in the HTML/CSS).

HTML:

```
    <div class="days">
    <div class="days-container">
    <div class="dairy"></div>
    <div class="beef"></div>
    <div class="pork"></div>
    <div class="eggs"></div>
    <div class="chicken"></div>
    </div> <!-- end days-container-->
    </div> <!-- end days -->
```

CSS:

```
.days {
 float: left;
 height:330px;
 width: 1em;
}

.days-container {
position:relative;
height: 330px;
}

.chicken {
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
background-color: #00AAFF;
 }
```

Comment: this isn't what you want? => http://jsfiddle.net/wDtRR/1/

Comment: IUs the width set in js to? else, there's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don't see it is because it has a 0px width. Try giving .chicken a 100% width.

Comment: Also, perhaps it's not rendering the empty element, try puting a non-breaking space in (`&nbsp;`)